# Your app was disapproved and unpublished due to a policy violation

Tags: google-play

After review, your app has been rejected and wasn't published due to a policy violation. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play. However, the previous version of your app may be subject to removal if you do not resolve the issue outlined below.

Eligibility Issue
Login Credentials
In order for us to review your app for compliance with Developer Program Policies, we will need you to provide valid login credentials for your app.
If users need credentials to access your app, please provide all appropriate credentials via Play Console.
If you previously supplied credentials, please ensure that they have not expired.
If your app normally uses 2-Step Verification (e.g. SMS verification), biometrics (e.g. a fingerprint or face scan) or a location-dependent password (e.g. geo-gate), please provide valid demo credentials that we can use instead.
We could not access in-app content due to app connection error.
What do I do

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmZ8k.png)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not programming, and instead about a policy question related to app store rejection.

Answer (score 1):

Go to playconsole
open app
then in side menu at end  open policy status
then press on app content
choose some functionality is restricted
then enter demo login credentials submit it